# contentResolver.query() works on emulators but not on real devices

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

My app "calls" the device's app that allows user to insert a new contact.
After a contact is saved on the device, I want to "query" the Uri of that contact.

My code works on emulators (Android 4, 5, 6, 7) but not on my Huawei P8, and I cant' understand why.

First, I request permission both in the Activity and in `Manifest.xml`:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String [] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, 
                                                       Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 
                                 101);

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

This is the code of my app

1) I "call" the device's app that manages the Contacts

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true); 
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_FRIEND_CODE);
```

2) after saving a new contact, my app comes back to foreground and the `onActivityResult()` method is called:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode){
          case ADD_FRIEND_CODE:
          if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){               
                /*I get the URI of the contact. This works both
                on emulator and real device*/
                Uri lastContactUri = data.getData();      

                ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                Cursor cursor =  contentResolver.query(lastContactUri, null, null, null, null);    

                /*On emulator the cursor is full, on real device is empty*/                  
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {                    
                    cursor.moveToPrevious();
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {                        
                        String name = "";
                        if (cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME) > -1) {
                            name  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        }
                    Toast.makeText(this, name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } 
                cursor.close();                   
                break;
        }
    }
```

Does anybody understand why my code works on many emulators and not on my real devices.

Comment: check if permissions are enabled in settings. Show the error Logs as well.

Comment: If I check my mobile I can see that my app has "contact" permissions. I don't get any error on my app, just a empty Cursor.

Comment: print the value of `lastContactUri` to the log, also after getting the cursor, print `cursor.getCount();`

Comment: The problem seems to be the call to Intent.ACTION_INSERT. I open a new post that explains better what happens. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275087/contentresolver-querycontactscontract-contacts-content-uri-return-0-count-c