# contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI...) return 0 count Cursor if called after Intent.ACTION_INSERT

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

I'm getting a weird behavior when testing my app on **Huawei P8**. Everything works nice on emulators (android version 4, 5, 6, 7) and on **ASUS** (android 6) and **Samsung Galaxy S2** (Android 4.2).

The following steps work both on physical device and emulators. After calling `contentResolver.query()` I get a Cursor with all the contacts of my device.

1. I open my app
2. I call `contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI...);`

The following steps work everywhere except on my **Huawei P8**; with my **Huawei P8**, and only with it, I get a 0 count Cursor

1. I open my app
2. From my app, I open an `Intent` to add a new contact on the device
3. I add a new contact or I close the activity without adding contact
4. I call `contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);`

This is how I get the contacts on the device:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();    
Cursor cursor =  contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

This is how I open, from my app, the activity to add a new contact on the device

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
```

It's seems that after calling `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI)` the contact table is "locked".

Do I have to "close" the Intent someway to be able to query `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`?

IMPORTANT: if, for example, instead of `Intent.ACTION_INSERT` I call `Intent.ACTION_CALL` I don't get any problem and I'm able to query successfully `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`. So, the problem is  "calling" `Intent.ACTION_INSERT` and after query `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` on Huawei P8.

Thank you in adavance.

Comment: are you able to constantly recreate this behavior? sounds very strange... what if you delay the query for a couple of seconds after getting back from the insert intent?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to constantly recreate this behavior! I also tried to wait almost a minute  before make a query on ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, but I keep on getting a 0 count Cursor

Comment: test on some other device, maybe it's a bug in your phone

Comment: I tried on an Asus, and it works. It's a bug of Huawei P8!!! What the hell!

Comment: try `intent.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);`

Comment: @Ashutosh Sagar  I already tried it man. It seems a Huawei P8 bug :(

Comment: You can add contacts programmatically by `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 001);
            values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "1-800-GOOG-411");
            values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
            values.put(Phone.LABEL, "Nirav");
            Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);` and then pass an Intent with this URI

Comment: @MDP yeah, this stuff happens...

Comment: @marmor I also tried my code on samsung galaxy S2 and it works! It's officially a Huawei P8 bug!!

Comment: @AshutoshSagar I'll try your solution to see if I can "bypass" the problem with your code! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*(For completeness, I'll make this an answer)*

This might be a device bug, try the same code on some other device.

Comment: I tried on Samsung S2 (android 4.2) and ASUS (android 6) and my code works. It seems to really be a Huawei P8 bug